# Get a value from multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I got this array from API call, I can get the name of the event using the cell number, using this PHP code:
`$eventName = $str['result'][0]['tokens'][0]['value'];`

But the number of cells may change, and I need to use the key. How can I get the value "Programming 2018" where the name is "Event"?

Here is the array:
[image: Here is the array]

Comment: Just loop over the `tokens` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the tokens would give you the result:

```
foreach( $str['result'][0]['tokens'] as $key => $value )
{
    if ( $value[ "name" ] == "Event" )
    {
        $Result = $value[ "value" ];
    }
}

echo $Result;
```

Is this what you've been looking for?